# 3 -> 1 routing issue

Tags: networking, iptables, routing

I've had this working before, but I can't get it right on a new machine. I have the following setup on a ubuntu install as a router.

```
 192.168.2.0/24 p34p1 wifi1 -------------|
 192.168.1.0/24 p33p1 wired -------------|------Internet p32p1 
 192.168.3.0/24 p34p1 wifi2 -------------|      192.168.0.0/24
```

This might look overly complicated but it keeps the kids gaming traffic off my regular network, which can't use it on a console anyway. At present all three segments can talk to the internet, but cannot talk to each other in different segments as required.

routing

```
 Kernel IP Routing table
 Destination     Gateway       Genmask         Iface
 0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1   0.0.0.0         p32p1
 192.168.0.0     *             255.255.255.0   p32p1
 192.168.0.1     *             255.255.255.255 p32p1
 192.168.1.0     *             255.255.255.0   p33p1
 192.168.2.0     *             255.255.255.0   p34p1
 192.168.3.0     *             255.255.255.0   p35p1
```

iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 998 packets, 64328 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 115 packets, 9157 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 30271 packets, 1701429 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 172 packets, 17314 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
30982  1739286 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      p32p1   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  102     8264            all  --  *      p33p1   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   61     7327            all  --  *      p34p1   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    7     1603            all  --  *      p35p1   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

my iptables rules are turning into mush.

Any Assistance appreciated, thank-you

Comment: `iptables -L` doesn't give us your NAT rules, which we need. Please do `sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L` and edit your question adding the output. Since your default policy for your FORWARD chain is accept, you don't actually need any of those rules.

Comment: iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L added

Comment: I think I found a partial, the networks there, but no gateways. Will look into that next

Answer (score 0):

This missing gateways were the problem to the solution ;)  Works much more betterer that way.

```
route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.2.1
```

repeat for each nic

Without the gateway even if it knows the network is there it won't work